# Positioning a JQuery/HTML script on blog on Squarespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, squarespace

I am trying to position the JQuery animation nicely (lower, centered) on this page:

http://www.edoardocroce.com/

I am using snippets of code that I found here and there. You can find the code that I am using here below.

Anybody can tell me if this is possible without much work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/bubbles.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var myName = "Edo's Blog";
var letterColors=[black,black,black];
if(10 < 9) {
    bubbleShape = "circle";
}
else {
    bubbleShape = "square";
}
drawName(myName, letterColors);
bounceBubbles();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: by the looks of it, if you want it centered, place `<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>` inside of `<header id="header"></header>`

Answer (score 0):

Just add styling to `#myCanvas`, or add a element above it with the styling, like:

```
<div id="header"><canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas></div>
```

and on your css:

```
#header { text-align: center; width: 100% }
#myCanvas { margin-top: 100px }
```

This will center the canvas and lower the header by 100px.

Answer (score 0):

add css to center and lower your canvas... for example:

```
#myCanvas {
   margin: 0 auto; /*to center*/
   margin-top: 80px; /*to lower*/
}
```

In case you don't know, css goes in the head, like this

```
<head>
  <style>
    #myCanvas {
       margin: 0 auto; /*to center*/
       margin-top: 80px; /*to lower*/
    }
  </style>
 .....
</head>
```

Or you can link to an external css sheet, the 'proper' way to do things.